# String should only contain characters '?', '0' and '1'

Tags: java, if-statement, character

Im trying to solve a problem which reads only characters '?', '0' and '1' from the console. I have been using the following if statement, but it only works when all three are included in the string.

How should the statement look like if I only want '?', '0' and '1'? I want the program to stop if I use for instance "10?=".

```
 if(text.contains("?") && text.contains("0") && text.contains("1"))
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: Loop on the string, check every character with `charAt`, set a flag to false and bail out as soon as you encounter a character that is neither ?, 0 or 1. Then use that flag as the condition in the `if` statement.

Comment: seems like a case for regular expressions: see Oracle's tutorial [Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) or the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class

Comment: Using a regex this would become `if(text.matches("[\\?01]+"))` (assuming the string must not be empty). Without regex you basically do what Federico suggested.

Comment: Probably better to compile the pattern in advance if it's used often as the creation of the decision tree is relatively heavy operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for this with the following pattern: `[?01]+` which means 1 or more instances of the characters ?, 0 or 1. if you want to limit it to 0 or more instances of any of them you can use this pattern instead: `[?01]*` or for exactly 1 you can just omit the `*` at the end (`[?01]`)

The usage would be as follow:

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[?01]+");

private boolean isMatching(String s) {
   return pattern.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

An example of the usage would be (please note that in this case both the function and the pattern need to be static):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(isMatching("?"));
     System.out.println(isMatching("?A"));
     System.out.println(isMatching("N?"));
     System.out.println(isMatching("3"));
     System.out.println(isMatching("01"));
}
```

Which will follow this output:

```
true
false
false
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)) to read from the console you can do it like this.

- `[^01?]+` - use one or more characters other than `0,1, ?` as the input delimiter.

For demo purposes I am use a String as input.

```
String testString = "ksks1ksks111;?001ksksksk10101 skksksk0ksks1ksk101010101jsjs";

Scanner s = new Scanner(testString).useDelimiter("[^01\\?]+");

while (s.hasNext()) {
    String in = s.next();
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

prints

```
1
111
?001
10101
0
1
101010101
```

To actually read from the console you can set use `System.in` in place of `testString` above.  To terminate the input you can check for a specific combination of characters or signal an `eof` for the console.